# How many degrees do you have to rotate a regular polygon by to ensure that the bottom edge is horizontal?

Tags: geometry

If you have a regular polygon of n sides, drawn in such a way that there is a vertex pointing directly right (the polygon is circumscribed by a circle of radius r, so the right most vertex is located at Cartesian coordinates (r, 0)), how would you calculate the minimum number of degrees you have to rotate the polygon by (clockwise) to ensure that there is:

a) an edge pointing directly downwards?
b) a vertex pointing directly upwards?
For polygons with an odd number of sides, a) and b) are the same.

For context, I'm creating algorithmically generated images, purely for fun.
I've been working them out by trial and error for different shapes, but I want to see how to calculate the angle of rotation needed, if anyone can point me in the right direction?
As an example, for n=3 (a triangle), rotating by 30° clockwise from the default orientation gives a triangle with a vertex pointing directly up.

Edit: here is the result of playing with @Daniel Methias' suggestion(s):
[image: rotated polygons]

Comment: @Karl that will be 360/n degrees

Comment: Rotation needed will be one of $\{0,\frac{90}{n},\frac{180}{n},\frac{270}{n}\}$. Play with that a bit.

Comment: @DanielMathias see above edit to question.  I'm still unsure as to why or for which value of n a particular rotation would be appropriate.

Comment: Highlight the desired rotations in your image and look for a pattern. I didn't bother to work out the 'why', but the 'for which' should become clear.

Comment: @DanielMathias Image updated to include highlighted rotations of interest (I added a 'vertex downwards' category in addition to the other categories mentioned in the question).  I can see the patterns here and can use this to identify which rotation to use via conditional logic, but I still think a better way would be to calculate the angle directly, based on n.  I'm just not sure how to do that.  I need to know something about the theory behind these rotations.